I am trying to update but its giving error and I am not getting whats's the issue
jitendra@jitendra-Inspiron-15-3520:~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled:
  libcjson1 libavdevice60 ffmpeg libpostproc57 libavcodec60 libavutil58
  libswscale7 libswresample4 libavformat60 libavfilter9
Learn more about Ubuntu Pro at https://ubuntu.com/pro
The following upgrades have been deferred due to phasing:
  cloud-init file-roller ubuntu-pro-client ubuntu-pro-client-l10n
The following packages will be upgraded:
  base-files brave-browser bsdextrautils bsdutils eject fdisk gnome-shell
  gnome-shell-common gnome-text-editor google-chrome-stable libblkid1
  libfdisk1 libmount1 libpq5 libpython3-dev libpython3-stdlib libsmartcols1
  libuuid1 linux-firmware mount python-apt-common python3 python3-apt
  python3-dev python3-distupgrade python3-minimal python3-venv rfkill
32 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 484 MB/714 MB of archives.
After this operation, 5,624 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Err:1  base-files amd64 13ubuntu10.1
  500  Software caused connection abort [IP: 185.125.190.82 80]
Err:2 noble-updates/main amd64 bsdutils amd64 1:2.39.3-9ubuntu6.1
  500  Software caused connection abort [IP: 185.125.190.82 80]
Err:24 noble-updates/main amd64 fdisk amd64 2.39.3-9ubuntu6.1
  500  Software caused connection abort [IP: 185.125.190.82 80]
Err:25noble-updates/main amd64 gnome-shell amd64 46.0-0ubuntu6~24.04.4E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?


@DavidDE I think the answer to this question that was posted resolves these issues by getting to the root of the problem.

500  Software caused connection abort500-series messages are server errors (not your local machine).
Try a different mirror.

How to switch APT mirror from the commandline?

